# How to search for a word in a sentence and give sentence as output

Tags: python

I have two lists :

```
list1 = ["Name of company", "Banking", "JP Morgan", "Citibank", "Goldman Sachs", "Bank of America", "Big 4", "KPMG", "Deloitte (US GAAP)","EY (IDT)",
"Software/IT", "Infosys", "FMCG", "P & G", "Pidilite Indutries", "Indigo Paints", "Divi Labs"]

list2 = ["divi", "GAAP", "Morgan"]
```

Now I want Python to search list2 items in list1 and give the output as the sentence in which the item is found.

For example,
the output of the above thing should be ["Divi labs", "Deloitte (US GAAP)", "JP Morgan")

PS: ignore case differences, i can solve it through .lower()

The actual list1 contains over 1000 sentences and actual list2 contains over 100 words. The above is just an example.

I have tried the following:

```
For x in list1:
    if x in list2:
       print (x)
```

But you know it won't work.

Comment: What is the output for keywords matching more than one sentence?

Comment: hey thats a nice thought. leme ask deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over `list2` and check if the element in present in each word of `list1`.

```py
[y for y in list1 for x in list2 if x.lower() in y.lower()]
```

Comment: Deepak, what if there are repetitions in list 1. Can you rewrite the code such that all repeated words in sentences are also captured?

Comment: Just swap the order of iteration between `list2` and `list1`. That should do it. I've updated the code as well.